# How to display a profil for google+ after login with cordova ionic application?

Tags: android, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

I use this tutorial https://github.com/anilkumar007/google-login,

i succes to login in google+ but i do now how to display a profil .

Answer (score 0):

you need to query the google+ api to get the information about the person who just logged in.

Then you display the response information in your app.

please check https://developers.google.com/+/web/api/rest/latest/people/get
there is a js api that you can use